# Displaying a floor division

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a dynamic display for a long process using Python 3.2.5, and this function do not work:

```
def displayProgress(progress, total):
    print("Getting anagrams and saving them...", progress, "/", total," or: ", progress//total*100, "% done.", sep="", end="\r")
```

For example, with `progress=1000`and`total=4000`, instead of displaying :

> Getting anagrams and saving them...1000/4000 or: 25% done.

It displays:

> Getting anagrams and saving them...1000/4000 or: 0% done.

If someone can help to figure out how to resolve this.
Thanks for reading and helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floor division removes the fraction before you multiply with 100:

```
>>> 1000/4000
0.25
>>> 1000//4000
0
```

You want to multiply by 100 *then* use floor division:

```
>>> 1000 * 100 // 4000
25
```

or applied to your `print()` call:

```
print("Getting anagrams and saving them...", progress, "/", total, " or: ", progress * 100 // total, "% done.", sep="", end="\r")
```

You may want to use string formatting here, and leave the rounding to the `%` formatter (which automatically multiplies your input number by 100 and applies `f` formatting to the result, adding the percentage sign for you):

```
print("Getting anagrams and saving them... {}/{} or: {:.0%} done.".format(
          progress, total, progress / total),
      end="\r")
```

This will, of course, round up too when the fractional percentage is over .5; 200 out of 300 will be displayed as `67%`.

Demo:

```
>>> progress, total = 1000, 4000
>>> "Getting anagrams and saving them... {}/{} or: {:.0%} done.".format(progress, total, progress / total)
'Getting anagrams and saving them... 1000/4000 or: 25% done.'
```